# Open and view PDF inside Android app

Tags: java, android, pdf

How to open and view PDF inside Android app? I need to use it in commercial app and it must work offline.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I tried to find a library for this purpose. But all of them have a GPL license.

Comment: I tried to use sourceforge.net/projects/andpdf (LGPL), but it works very slow. Other libraries are licensed under GPL.

Answer (score 2):

There's three options:

1)Use an external viewer application.  Vino shows you how to do this.

2)Use an open source library.  There's one or two, but they really suck

3)Pay a lot of money for a commercial library.  The big ones are PdfTron (will cost you a few tens of thousands per year), Qoppa (will cost you thousands a year), and Raede (with cost about 1K per app).  Thats pretty much the order of performance and features I've seen too-  pdftron best, raede worst.

Comment: I tried to use http://sourceforge.net/projects/andpdf/, but it works very slow.

Comment: THe other problem is it doesn't support a lot of PDFs.  How bad that is depends on what type of pdfs you generate.  It was a deal breaker for my project (3d cad renders)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
     try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/userguide.pdf"),
                    "application/pdf"); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Application Available to View PDF.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

To run this you need to be installed any pdf view application before.

Comment: Your `Uri` will not normally work, as files on internal storage are not readable by third-party applications.

Comment: Yes you are right need to copy the pdf to specific path in sdcard before reading it.

Comment: I can not use third-party applications.